# Best practice for documenting javascript library dependencies

Tags: javascript, dependencies, conventions

So you're creating a bunch of code in an external .js file that requires jQuery and a few of its plugins, or MooTools, or perhaps some more esoteric libraries. Obviously the actual "include" is done in the host HTML page in the HEAD section as you load in each script.

But as a best practice for portability, what built-in features, or widely-adopted conventions exist within your JavaScript .js file to ensure that the next schmoe who uses your code remembers to also include those other required libraries?

I'm looking for some consensus from the developer community, so please be sure to vote for the answer that seems most common or that you are the most familiar with.

Comment: Can't you explicitly check for your dependencies and throw exceptions if they're not satisfied?

Comment: Sure can, and probably should do. But I also want something more visible, like a "use" in Perl, an "import" in ActionScript, or a "include" or "require" in PHP. Not that I expect to discover some heretofore undisclosed JavaScript directive, but at least a documentation best practice that a lot of developers can agree on.

Comment: Ah.  Well, yes, the lack of a "module" solution in JavaScript is something that many, many people bemoan.  The future spec beyond ES5, called "Harmony", may introduce some sort of solution to this problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery UI adds the dependencies of their widgets in the file header:

```
/*
* jQuery UI Effects Bounce @VERSION
*
* Copyright 2011, AUTHORS.txt (http://jqueryui.com/about)
* Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
* http://jquery.org/license
*
* http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Bounce
*
* Depends:
* jquery.effects.core.js
*/
```

Now unfortunately JavaScript dependency managers are used way less than they should, but if you can make your libraries users switch to one you wouldn't have to worry about that at all:

- [StealJS](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=stealjs)
- [Jingo](http://code.google.com/p/jingo/)
- [YUI loader](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/yuiloader/)
- [Pyramid Dependency Manager](http://joel.inpointform.net/software-development/pyramid-js-a-web-dependency-manager/)

Checking explicitly might be a good idea, too, since you can dynamically react if certain plugins are or are not available (e.g. either throw an exception if the jQuery UI dialog hasn't been found or just degrade gracefully and show a simple modal window):

```
if(!$.isFunction($.fn.dialog)) {
    throw "Could not find jQueryUI dialog. Please include jQuery UI";
}
```

That way your script doesn't have to break entirely if an optional dependency is not met.

Comment: I like the idea of adopting the same documentation practice as used in a popular framework like jQuery.

Comment: +1 for dependency managers. I've never used them, but the concept is great.

Comment: Especially in larger applications! I'm using StealJS and loading everything in dev mode is about 200 requests. Compressed and bundled up it comes down to two requests, is about 70% smaller and incredibly fast. @Tom Auger Putting dependency descriptions into the documentation helps, but it still doesn't enforce dependencies.

Answer (score 6):

For the Visual Studio developers out there you may want to try blocks like these in your header

```
/// <reference path="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.6-vsdoc.js" />
/// <reference path="thirdparty/ba-debug.js" />
/// <reference path="thirdparty/underscore.js" />
```

While this doesn't resolve your dependencies, it does document them, AND it gives you intellisense in Visual Studio...

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385682.aspx, then look for *References Directives* (no *a name* or *id* to link directly to, sorry...)

Comment: tangential comment: this is my latest favorite external vsdoc file:

`/// <reference path="https://raw.github.com/appendto/amplify/1.0.0/vsdoc/amplify-vsdoc.js" />`

Answer (score 3):

my js headers look like this:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
//  src:        www.someDomain.com/js/modules/etc
//  author:     someguy
//  date:       6-22-11
//  intent:     what is the purpose / use of this module
//  package:    prototype parent
//  requires:   jquery.1.4.js
//              fancybox
//              etc
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Any dependencies are then quite clear to anyone on my team, and this has proven pretty reliable. As a (hopefully) secondary measure, I will always test for those dependencies at runtime and throw up an alert should a script not be included.

Comment: Looks pretty clean and clear! Ever consider doing ASCII art? :)

Answer (score 0):

I always believe that software engineers should always know, or at least be reminded, be forced to know what they are doing. They should keep the list of the dependencies by themselves and be very clear about why he/she needs them. There are not many js files to include in a page anyway.

I think it should be nice if the browsers have the jQuery and some nice plugins with them, so we do not need to inclcude them in in the page to save traffic though.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, your approach is "no standards, each man for himself, read the code and figure it out"?

Comment: Not as bad as how you understand though. If there are 50+ js files need to be included, we may need to figure out a way to manage it. But if there are only 2 - 5, we do better to remember them by ourselves, so we know exactly what we are doing. But if some page has 50+ js files included, me as a user will try to disable javascript on my browser with the hope my browser can load the page faster.

Comment: Uhm, yeah I have - coincidentally - exactly 50 JS files at the moment in my project.  During debug.  At release, they get combined into fewer files.  Managing dependencies is still a chore though.

Comment: Alright then ... 50 JS files can be outrageous. You need to figure out some way to combine them when you release them. In my projects, I always (at least make the effort) to keep a clear picture in my head which one depends on which one. If the root is the jQuery, the dependency tree is really not so hard to remember. But for 50 JS files, I will need to draw a picture and post it next to my desk.